# How do I delete a node in appsettings.json using appsettings.Development.json?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I am struggling a bit with how the `appsettings.Development.json` *overrides* or otherwise *merges* with the `appsettings.json`. I am not sure how to "clear" a node out of appsettings.json by using the appsettings.Development.json file.

For reference, I am using the default builder as seen here https://github.com/aspnet/MetaPackages/blob/rel/2.0.0-preview1/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore/WebHost.cs#L159-L160

### appsettings.json

```json
{
  "Policy": {
    "roles": [
      {
        "name": "inventoryAdmin",
        "subjects": [ "bob", "alice" ],
        "identityRoles": [ "ActiveDirectory-Role-Manager" ]
      },
  ]
 }
}
```

Given that example, why can I not do the following in my:

### appsettings.Development.Json:

```json
{ "Policy": { "Roles": [] } }
```

or

```json
{ "Policy": { "Roles": null } }
```

When I check the output via something like `Configuration.Get<PolicyServer.Local.Policy>().Roles` I still get 3 roles back.

This question is hopefully going to guide me on how I can override a node and not just clear it. So I am hoping to start simple and work my way there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All of the settings that go into your `IConfiguration` instance are simply key-value pairs. Take the following, simplified example JSON:

```json
{
    "Roles": [
        { "Name": "Role1", "Subjects": [ "Alice", "Bob" ] },
        { "Name": "Role2", "Subjects": [ "Charlie" ] }
    ]
}
```

Although this is essentially a tree structure, it maps into the following key-value pairs when added to your `IConfiguration` instance (there are some additional empty values here, but they're not part of this discussion):

- `Roles` =
- `Roles:0:Name` = `Role1`
- `Roles:0:Subjects:0` = `Alice`
- `Roles:0:Subjects:1` = `Bob`
- `Roles:1:Name` = `Role2`
- `Roles:1:Subjects:0` = `Charlie`

You can see that this mimics the hierarchy of your JSON, where the names are object properties and the numbers are indexes into arrays. That first one is important: There's a key of `Roles` which has no value, because values can only be simple strings and its just a parent in itself.

Now, when you add an extra JSON file to the `IConfiguration` instance setup, it maps to a new set of key-value pairs that get applied on top of those that exist. Take the following additional JSON:

```json
{
    "Roles": []
}
```

This simply overwrites the existing `Roles` key and sets it to, well, the same value it already has: *nothing*. The same applies if you use `null` in your JSON file - that's just how this stuff works.

In terms of a solution here, I suggest seeing if you can rework your `appsettings.json` approach. For example, you might be able to put the role configuration itself into e.g. an `appsettings.Production.json` file and leave the default version blank so that it doesn't exist in your development environment. In other words, try and model your different `appsettings.json` files to be additive themselves.